# How can I utilize EntityCollection of type <Interface> using a partial class with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I'm using partial classes. One class is generated from EntityFramework. Another class I generate myself so that I can implement an interface. The interface will be used so two libraries/assemblies will not know about each other but will be able to implement the common interface.

My custom interface declares property EntityCollection(**ITimesheetLabors**) but my EntityFramework generates EntityCollection(TimesheetLabors) so the compiler tells me that my class doesn't implement EntityCollection(ITimesheetLabors) which is understandable. However, what is the best method of making my partial class return the collection of interfaces I desire?

Should the get of my collection property of my partial class return a newly instantiated EntityCollection so that it can cast the concrete types to my interface? It seems a bit of overkill. What am I missing?

```
public interface ITimesheet //My Interface
{
    EntityCollection<ITimesheetLabors> Timesheets {get;set;} 
}

public partial class Timesheet//Class generated by Entity Framework
{
    EntityCollection<TimesheetLabors> Timesheets {get;set;} 
}

public partial class Timesheet : ITimesheet  //My Partial Class that implements my interface
{
    EntityCollection<ITimesheetLabors> Timesheets {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: If they are `partial` they are not different classes; they are the **same class**, just defined in separate *.cs files.

Comment: You actually cant do this in c# at all you cant assign a collection of a concrete type to a collection of its interface

Comment: I appreciate your responses but maybe you're not hitting the point. I did misquote the term "in another class" but I meant "in another file". Correcting that misstatement doesn't answer my question. Also, I do know that you can't assign a concrete to a collection directly although you can create another collection and add the concrete to the collection by casting as the interface. So, do you have a suggestion for the best practice to return my desired type? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't support interfaces so the only way is using both original property generated by EF and your interface property which will internally access the generated property.

Btw. your design smells - on the one side you are trying to hide your entities by using interfaces and in the same time you are exposing `EntityCollection` => you are making your upper layer dependent on EF. The common approach is to do the opposite design - hide EF and use POCOs (interfaces are usually not needed).

Comment: I would've probably used another word than "smells" but I understand your point and agree. What I'm trying to lead into based off of my question, in best practices, should utilize a different return type? So, do you have a suggestion of which type of collection I should return?  IList? IEnumerable? I'd like something serializable. Also, in that regard, on the get property should I create a new list to return which may not be most efficient or should I instantiate it in the class, populate it, but how would I monitor new adds/deletes from the EntityCollection? Thank You.

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5 or newer? `EntityCollection` is directly used only with `EntityObject` based entities - if you are using .NET 4.0 or newer why are you not using POCOs? Why do you want something serializable?

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0. I was using POCO's at one point by having them created with the T4 Templates but they were not posting properly through Entity Framework and it became more of a hassle than a benefit. Basically, I'm the only programmer here writing windows apps so I have very minimal time to do things the altruistic way if I run into hindrances. I still utilized T4 Templates but had them create entities and it has been much easier and it also allows me to utilize POCO's later when I get a chance to do so.

Comment: I have to work with two different systems: ISeries & SQL Server. They have similar but different table structures which is one reason why I wanted the use of interfaces since their POCO objects would be similar yet different. I may need to union two different queries for example.  If I create a webservice, I have been told that I need the classes to be serialized and the lists as well so that they can be easily converted to XML for SOAP calls. My interface would eventually act as my contract for that, etc.